# Euler-Lagrange example proof

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, euler-lagrange-equation

The original version was totally incorrect. This question can be removed. Sorry for the bad post.

Comment: You have written $$2 - \frac{d}{dx} (3) = 0$$ based upon the definition of the ELE, but the above line equals $2$. You then integrated this problem, which doesn't make sense as you require a $y'$ term to integrate when there isn't one.

Comment: I am trying to create an example of Euler-Lagrange equation with a function that has all three arguments. But I keep getting into situation where I cannot solve the Euler-Lagrange equation that I get.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach doesn't work because your Euler-Lagrange equation is inconsistent. Since $$J=3y\left( 2\right) -3y\left( 1\right) - \frac{2^2-1^2}{2} + 2\int_1^2 ydx=\frac{9}{2} + 2\int_1^2 ydx,$$the task is equivalent to extremising $\int_1^2 ydx$. That the Euler-Lagrange equation is still inconsistent hints at the fact that there is no extremal choice of $y$. The boundary values are consistent with $y=2x+1+A\left( x-1\right)\left( x-2\right)$, so we can give $J$ any value with suitable $A$.

Comment: Let's assume that my $F$ would be that kind that it has an extremal. Is my reasoning then correct? Or how does one solve Euler lagrange equation?

Comment: @Zzz Extremising a functional is equivalent to satisfying its Euler-Lagrange equation(s), which is possible iff there is no inconsistency, which there is here because the equation is $0=1$.

Comment: Do you happen to have an example of $F(x,y,y')$ that has all those three arguments and it has extremal? I have been trying and trying and I end up in a situation where I have something like $yx+C-y'=0$ and I cannot solve it.

Comment: @Zzz Solving Euler-Lagrange equations is in general difficult; there's no general method for that, any more than for solving differential equations in general. The point of extremising actions is to obtain these equations, not to solve them. Your example is of the form $y'+Py=Q$ with $P=-x,\,Q=C$, which has a well-known solution technique. The usual pedagogical example of an $x$-dependent Lagrangian whose Euler-Lagrange equation is consistent is $g\left( x\right)\left(y'^2 -V\left( y\right)\right)$ for functions $g,\,V$.

Comment: I have tried to find Euler-Lagrange where I can use integrating method, but with bad luck. If you integrate the $F_{y}$ term, isn't what you get $y$-something plus constant $C$?

Comment: You shouldn't need to integrate $F_y$; the point is you differentiate $F_{y'}$ to obtain $F_y$. Note in particular that the Euler-Lagrange equation is $F_y-\partial_x F_{y'}=0$, not $F=0$.

Comment: Oh, do you mean that $\frac{d}{dx}(y')=y''$?